# Proving $f'(x)>0$ implies growing function using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (for every bounded sequence, there exists a convergent subsequence), how would one go about proving that $f'(x)>0$ on an interval $[a,b]$ implies that $f(x)$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, i.e.

$$f'(x)>0 \implies \forall x_1,x_2\in[a,b], \ f(x_1)<f(x_2) \ \text{for} \ x_1<x_2$$

I've been instructed to proceed with a proof by contradiction, and can vaguely see how one would go about proving it...$\exists \ x_3 \in[x_1,x_2]$...yet don't see how the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Well to apply Bolzano-Weierstraß we first need a sequence. How to get that sequence? Well, assume the premise is false. Then there must exist some $x_l,x_r\in [a,b]$, $x_l < x_r$ such that $f(x_l) \ge f(x_r)$

Take the center point $x_c = \frac{x_r+x_l}{2}$. There are 3 possible ways how  $f(x_c)$ can relate to $f(x_l)$ and $f(x_r)$:

1. $f(x_c)   > f(x_l) \ge f(x_r)$
2. $f(x_l) \ge f(x_c) \ge f(x_r)$
3. $f(x_l) \ge f(x_r)   > f(x_c)$

Divide and Conquer! (Can you take it from here?)

Comment: What do we conclude about each option? What are we essentially looking for? I'm struggling understanding what the sequence should converge to.

Comment: @schn try to construct a (not necessarily strictly) monotonically decreasing sequence. How would the existence of such a sequence conflict with the condition  $f'>0$? (try to draw a picture)